# Is there a resource in SqlServerDsc I can use to configure the ALTER TRACE server permission?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, dsc

Can I implement the following T-SQL code using a PowerShell DSC resource from the [SqlServerDsc](https://github.com/dsccommunity/SqlServerDsc/tree/f71cdc4b15b9af046777c3d7addbb6c00d09c25a) module?

```
USE master
GRANT ALTER trace TO [myUser]
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
SqlDatabasePermission Grant_Alter_Trace_Permission
{
    Ensure               = 'Present'
    Name                 = 'mySQLUser'
    Database             = 'master'
    PermissionState      = 'Grant'
    Permissions          = 'ALTER TRACE'
    ServerName           = 'sqltest.company.local'
    InstanceName         = 'MSSQLSERVER'
}
```

The resource fails with the following error:

PowerShell DSC resource DSC_SqlDatabasePermission  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: System.InvalidOperationException: The name 'mySqlUser' is neither a database user, database role (user-defined), or database application role in the database 'master'.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TRACE is a [Server Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) not a database permission.  So try `SqlServerPermission` instead of `SqlDatabasePermission` if such a thing exists.

You might be able to work around this by creating a user in Master for mySQLUser.  My guess is that DSC is checking for the existence of a database principal before running

`GRANT ALTER trace TO [MyUser]`

And that grant will succeed if the login exists, if you can persuade DSC to attempt it.

Comment: There is a resource to manage server level permissions ([`SqlPermission`](https://github.com/dsccommunity/SqlServerDsc/wiki/SqlPermission)) but unfortunately it's limited to the following permissions:  ConnectSql, AlterAnyAvailabilityGroup, ViewServerState, AlterAnyEndPoint.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was able to get past the first error but the process still failed with the following error: 

Failed to invoke DSC Set method: PowerShell DSC resource DSC_SqlDatabasePermission  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set the permissions for the login 'myUser' in the database 'master'. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The property 'ALTER TRACE' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: Ahh.  Looks like it's using SMO instead of just issuing SQL statements.